How to exclude a related object type from validation rule
I have an Object called 'Program' which is creating/inserting a Task record.
On the Task I have a validation rule for a specific profile which is blocking the creation of Program indirectly through a trigger.
I want to bypass this validation rule for the same profile (since it's being used by two different teams)
Is there a way to bypass the Task validation rule for this SObject Type on the same profile?

Is there a specific lookup field that relates the Task back to the Program? If so, you could check for this being specified (I.e. not ISBLANK) during creation (ISNEW is true) and not apply the validation in that case.

Please [edit] your question to add more detail, like whether there is a Lookup from Task to Program.

Hi @phill there is a lookup. But I couldn't find a way to put it in the validation rule. That value for lookup is not always being assigned.

Yes, You can bypass the validation rule for the specific profile. for that, you need to create a custom permission to bypass the validation rule.
Follow the steps:

Create a Custom Permission.
Create a Permission Set and assign the custom permission set.
Assign the Permission Set to a user.
Modify the Validation Rule.

    AND(
    NOT($Permission.Bypass_Task_Validation_Rule),
    /* existing validation rule conditions */
    )

$Permission.Bypass_Task_Validation_Rule refers to the custom permission. The validation rule will only apply if the custom permission is not set.
Refer to more detail: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/validation-rules/bypass-your-validation-rules

This isn't what is being asked for, since they already have the validation rule for a given profile. Kudos for using custom permissions though.

Thanks @tushar but the validation rule is to check for a different field for that same profile. So in short I want to create the record and bypass the validation rule for a same profile.

Yes, you can bypass validation rule in certain scenario.

Using Permission Set: Create Permission Set, Custom Permission, Associate Custom Permission with Permission Set, Modify Validation Rule, Assign Validation Rule. 
AND( $Profile.Name != "System Administrator", NOT($Permission.Bypass_Task_Validation_Rule) )


Again, not answering the question asked.
